# OpenGL ES 1.1 VBO performance for small buffers (sprites - 4 vertices)

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, vbo

My game uses sprites for which I need vertex and texture coordinate data. I only draw a quad (4 vertices that might sometimes change between frames) and I was wondering if it's really worth it to switch from glVertexPointer to VBOs/VAOs . I could test this myself but I don't currently have access to a device and I'm stuck with the simulator.